# How to write IList<T> to csv file using CsvHelper?

Tags: csvhelper

I just started playing with the [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#getting-started) component by Josh Close. But I haven't yet fully understood the concept of mapping. What I have is a class `Order` that looks like this:

```
public class Order
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

where `Address` looks like this:

```
public class Address
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'd like to write these classes to a csv file. Sample output could be something like this:

```
Order.Id;Order.Address.Name;Order.Address.City
1;"Bob Miller";"London"
```

I have two mapping classes `OrderMap` and `AddressMap`:

```
public sealed class OrderMap : CsvClassMap<Order>
{
  public OrderMap ()
  {
    Map (m => m.Id);
    Map (m => m.Addresses).Index (0);
  }
}

public sealed class AddressMap : CsvClassMap<Address>
{
  public AddressMap ()
  {
    Map (m => m.Name);
    Map (m => m.City);
  }
}
```

But that produces the following output:

```
Id,Addresses
1,CsvHelperClassMappingTest.Address
```

So, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the `CsvClassMap`s are used only for reading, not writing. To get the output you're looking for you simply need to map your complex `Order` object to a flat object that matches the layout you want in the CSV. Define your class like so:

```
class FlatOrder
{
    public FlatOrder(Order order)
    {
        Id = order.Id;
        var firstAddress = order.Address[0];
        AddressName = firstAddress.Name;
        AddressCity = firstAddress.City;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AddressName { get; set; }

    public string AddressCity { get; set; }
}
```

Then map and write your objects:

```
var flatOrders = orders.Select(o => new FlatOrder(o));
csv.WriteRecords(flatOrders);
```

If you're feeling lazy you could even use an anonymous type instead of defining one up front.

Comment: The suggested solution works. Can anyone confirm that `CsvClassMap` and auto mapping only work for reading purposes?

Comment: I'm clearly wrong about `CsvClassMap` only being used for reading. As you can see in [this test file] (https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper.Tests/CsvWriterMappingTests.cs) they are used for writing but I'm not sure about the rules for their use. I still believe that projecting to a flat object is simpler and more straightforward.